# re-including the entire contents of a folder in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have an included folder in visual studio, which contains mainly javascript files, CSS, images, etc.  These are not required for the website to run, and are altered not from Visual Studio but from other external processes.

I've been publishing to Windows Azure Websites, which require all files to be included so that they are uploaded as part of the package.

Is it possible to somehow click on a folder in the Solution Explorer, and 're-include' all it's contents?

The only option I found right now is to exclude and re-include, which due to the amount of files takes quite some time.  It takes ages to 'exclude' the folder.  Then, once it's ready I have to re-include which takes a long time as well.  Would like to at least do them in one operation.

Was wondering if there was a better process somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why you have exclude them all and include them again. Is it because the file names change or new files created often? If the file names stay the same and just the contents are changing you should not have to re-include them. If the external processes create new files now and then, then you should be able to click the "Show all files" option in solution explorer and then when you load the solution check the directory in solution explorer and any new files there include them.

hope that helps in some way. :)

Comment: Because these files would not have been created manually by myself. Sometimes they are added by other team members who do not use Visual Studio.  There are a lot of folders and a good nest of folder hierarchy, so manually including such files one by one would be an even much bigger hurdle

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. yup sounds like my options would not work in that case.